# Vim Environment Auto-Setup and Synchronization

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

When I remote into a new system for the first time, what's the recommended way of getting it setup so that it has all of my preferred plugins.

I'd like my local machine to be the template for vim plugins so that all changes to my local setup is synchronized across all other systems as I remote into them.

Is there a best practice for this?

Comment: git or github  ?

Comment: Did you consider a) mounting the remote filesystem locally or b) using the built-in remote browsing capabilities?

Comment: @romainl a) yes I had but dismissed it. b)... googling now

Answer (score 4):

Assume your remote server(s) have access to internet or same git-repo that your local machine can access.

- You push your vimrc file to git, then it is shared among your remote servers.
- Use a plugin management plugin, like Vundle, once you have the vimrc, then you have all the plugins defined there.
- Regarding the plugin-mgmt plugin, you can write a little shell script pull it from github to the right location. If you want it to be completely automatic, you can check in your vimrc, if this mgmt plugin not installed (copied), do `git clone` to fetch it.